# Tap/hover on iPad sometimes not working

Tags: html, ios, ipad, hover, tap

I'm trying to make simple hover effect on images. And it works fine on desktop, but has a problem on iPad. When I try to tap on right image, the right side of this image is not affecting on tap, the overlay doesn't show. But the left image and left side of the right image show overlay on tap fine. Maybe someone can explain this weird behavior?

**Html:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6 team-wrap">
  <div class="team-member text-center">
    <div class="team-img">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <h4 class="team-title">David Geller</h4>
    <span>CEO of Company</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 team-wrap">
  <div class="team-member text-center">
    <div class="team-img">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <h4 class="team-title">David Geller</h4>
    <span>CEO of Company</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.team-img img {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.team-member,
.team-img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.team-title {
  margin: 34px 0 8px;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(20,20,20,.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.team-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Codepen link:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQOKGG